# How to improve notes database performance?

Tags: performance, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a lotus notes database which has almost 34,000 documents in it, with a bunch of views almost 200. Thus performance is a major issue for me.

I have tried a couple of tricks such as:

> 1. Create indexes on server using Ctrl + Shift + F9
> 2. I run a scheduled agent on the database that runs every 3 hours the code is simple refresh each view

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView

    Set db = session.currentdatabase
    ForAll v In db.views
        v.refresh
    End ForAll
End Sub
```

But they don't seem to work that well? Any ideas or suggestion to improve performance on local and server copy will be great?

Also to let you know I have like 100 users who makes update at different intervals maybe 10-20 users per day.

Comment: Why do you need to update 200 views every 3 hours?

Comment: So when users make updates to documents these views take time to open ... so my plan was to refresh the views in background so the next user when he open the view is already refreshed ? is that a wrong idea ?

Comment: View.refresh does NOT do, what you want... It does not even affect the view index... You have to find the reason for the slow view performance instead of working around... 30.000 documents and 200 views is ridiculous for a NotesDatabase and should not even make you think about performance... There has to be very bad design in the views to make this little application have performance problems. Are there things like today or now in the views? Do you have a lot of reader fields? Are there many sortable columns? These things (among others) make databases slow, not 30.000 documents and 200 views

Comment: A couple of ideas: if the db is full-text indexed, in many cases you could use full-text index instead of a view (and remove the view). If a certain view is used f.e. by a nightly agent only, set the index option to "Manual" and do `view.refresh()` in the agent just before accessing the view (and do not refresh all your views in a background agent).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many possible reasons for poor performance, and many things that we could suggest. For example, we could talk about disk fragmentation. We could discuss what Domino version you have (which you didn't mention) and possible upgrades. We could discuss your server's i/o subsystem...

But the first and most glaringly obvious issue is that you have **too many views**!! The fact is that 30,000 documents is not at all unreasonable for a Notes database, even with a decent amount of new and edited documents per day. On a properly designed and maintained database on fairly basic hardware, this should perform just fine. I've seen databases with 100,000 or more docs with tens of thousands of new and deleted docs every day perform okay, but I've also seen them perform badly if, for example, deletion stubs weren't being purged often enough.

But I've digressed.... You have too many views, plain and simple. That's where you have to start. No matter what else you do, I can guarantee that a database with 200 views will perform poorly compared to a database with 20 views.  Some of your views may indeed be problems all by themselves due to poor design, so you need to look at every single one of them; but even before you look at the design, you have to ask: why is this view here? Who needs it? If I remove it, will anyone notice? Is there a different view or a better way to meet whatever needs this view meets?

Answer (score 4):

Define "performance" first of all. Are you talking about opening views? Or is it when you run code it is slow?
As Rich already said in his answer, you have way too many views. 30,000 documents is nothing, I have databases with millions of documenst and around 100 views, they work fine. 
I suspect that you may have a badly designed application. Perhaps you use date/time functions in views, GetNthDocument(), multiple @DbLookup on forms, etc?

Start by reading this white paper by Andre Guirard: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/d-ls-notesperformance/

You also have info here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Redbooks%3A+Lotus+Domino+Development+Best+Practices#action=openDocument&res_title=6.0_Performance_considerations&content=pdcontent

And here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27008849

Answer (score 3):

A couples of things to check:

Make sure none of your views selection formulas and column formulas contains any datetime functions like @now

Check view properties, on the Advanced tab set:
 Refresh: Auto, after first use
 Discard: If inactive for 45 days

Drop the update agent, the server should be able to take care of the index.